# If $A^2 = I$, then $A$ cannot be skew-symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I tried to prove it by contradiction but it didn’t work:
$A^2=I$ so $A=A^{-1}$ and $(\det(A))^2=1$

if $A=-A^T$

then $A^2=(-A^{2T})$

So $\det(A)=\det(-A^T)=-\det(A)$

since $\det(A)$ can’t equal $-\det(A)$ unless it is zero, we have a contradiction. Is that right?

Comment: Hint: Start from the equation $A^T=-A$ and use that to show what $A^2$ looks like.

Comment: is it becuase the det(A^2) cannot equal the det(-A^2T)?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 7):

For an $n\times n$-real matrix $A$, being skew-symmetric is equivalent to the condition that $$\langle Ax, y \rangle = - \langle x, Ay \rangle$$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, with the usual Euclidean product. If $A^2 = I$, then $$\langle Ax, Ax \rangle = - \langle x, A^2 x \rangle = - \langle x, x \rangle.$$
Choose any nonzero $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$; then $- \langle x, x \rangle < 0$, while $\langle Ax, Ax \rangle \geq 0$. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your determinant-based arguments.

For any $n\times n$ matrix and any scalar $c$, it holds that
$$
\det(A^T)=\det(A),\qquad \det(cA)=c^n\det(A)
$$
Thus we see that when $A$ is skew-symmetric we have
$$
\det(A)=\det(A^T)=\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det(A)
$$
so we see that when $n$ is odd the matrix $A$ is not invertible and $A^2=I$ is impossible. But this argument tells you nothing when $n$ is even.

---

From $A^2=I$ and $A=-A^T$, we deduce that $-AA^T=I$, which means that $AA^T=-I$. But $AA^T$ is positive semidefinite, while $-I$ is negative definite.